# How to recover crontab jobs from filesystem

Tags: crontab

On my system I have fedora 13, which I can't get to boot right now.

I'm now running ubuntu 11.10 from a different partition.

From ubuntu I can read the fedora partition.

In fedora I had some cron jobs, which I could list by typing `contab -l`

Now that I can't get fedora to boot, is there a way to recover the cron jobs from the file system used by fedora when I'm running ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cronjobs are most likely stored under `/var/spool/cron`

Answer (score 2):

You can find cron jobs in `/etc/crontab` file and following directories:
- `/etc/cron.d/`
- `/var/spool/cron/`
If your `/etc/crontab` file contains following lines, you can find shell scripts in mentioned directories too:

```
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly  
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily  
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly  
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

For example, `/etc/cron.hourly/`

Comment: Tried all your suggestions. The one that is working for me is `/var/spool/cron/`. Thanks

Comment: This directory is used to keep user-defined cron jobs... Anyway, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Look at /var/log/cron and what commands run for that user during the day and reconstruct from scratch

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

PanosIl is spot on. To expand on his answer, just grep for the "Cron" title lines in the log - which in my case was `/var/mail/root` file rather than dedicated log file  e.g

```
cat /var/mail/root | grep -B 4 -F "Subject: Cron"
```

Once you find the lines you are looking for you can retrieve the times and days from the log entry header.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1140252)